# Pythonic way to modify list

Tags: python, list, syntax, semantics

Is there a more pythonic way to tell the list which parts of it has to stay in it an which parts has to be removed?

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Wanted list:

```
[1,2,3,6,7]
```

I can do that this way:

```
wl = li[:-4]+li[-2:]
```

I'm looking for something like `li[:-4,-2:]` (in one statement/command)

Of course I can do `remove` but it can be used in many situations like:

Wanted list:

```
[3,4,5,6,7]
```

I can do `del li[0:2]`

But it's more common to do:

```
li[2:]
```

Comment: what is the logic behind the filtered list ? I mean what should be the output for a random set of integers ?

Comment: What is the problem with `wl = li[:-4]+li[-2:]`? Why do you want to compromise readability here? It is the best way (afaik)

Comment: `li[:-4]+li[-2:]` does not produce `[1,2,3,6]`.

Comment: The Pythonic way is to use what you already found. There is no more compact syntax.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was a typo, I meant [1,2,3,6,7].

Comment: @BhargavRao It would be little more compact and it is good that it is another option.

Comment: `li[3:5] = []` or  `del li[3:5]` seem ok to me

Comment: Or you could use `li.pop(3);li.pop(3)`, but I wouldn't call that pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Other than regular python lists, [NumPy arrays can be indexed by other sequence-like objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) (other than tuples) e.g. by regular python lists or by another NumPy array.

```
import numpy as np

li = np.arange(1, 8)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

wl = li[[0,1,2,5,6]]
# array([1, 2, 3, 6, 7])
```

Of course, this leaves you now with the problem of creating the index sequence (the regular python list `[0,1,2,5,6]` in this example), which puts you back on square one. (Unless you need to access several NumPy arrays at the same indices, so you create this index list once and then re-use it.)

You should probably only consider this if you have additional reasons to use NumPy in general or specifically NumPy arrays.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the output list to follow a certain logic, you can use the filter function.

```
filter(lambda x: x > 2, li)
```

or maybe

```
filter(lambda x: x < 4 or x > 5, li)
```

Comment: This is not the same at all, where is the OP filtering based on values?

Comment: Given that the OP didn't mentioned why he wanted the specific list, I assumed that he wanted to remove certain values which would follow a particular logic. I can see that you are right and that the assumption is baseless.